# Range validator inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, repeater, validation

I have a repeater that displays key-value pairs from a database table. Some of the fields in the table have min/max restriction. How can I add a range validator to the repeater and be able to use different ranges for different fields?

For example, some table fields are:

Idle Time: 20 (min 10, max 40)

Pickup Time: 60 (min 3, max 90)

When page is displayed it shows "Idle Time" (a label) and 20 in a text box, the nest row is "Pickup Time" (a label) and 60 in the textbox. I need to prevent the user from entering 80 or 5 in Idle Time, but 80 or 5 is valid for Pcikup Time.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top" class="BoldSmall">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Text='<%# Eval("GLOBALCONFIGNAME")%>' />
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top" class="BoldSmall">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbValue" CssClass="NormalSmall" Text='<%# Eval("GLOBALCONFIGVALUE")%>' Width="140" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

For textbox "tbValue" I need to add range validator, but the range change depending on what row of the table I am displaying in the repeater.

(e.g. first item of repeater has "Idle Time" as globalconfigname and 20 as globalconfigvalue; next item has "Pickup Time" as globalconfigname and 60 as globalconfigvalue, ...)

Thanks.

Comment: i think seeing code would benefit us

Comment: Just edited original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databind to MinimumValue and MaximumValue on the RangeValidator control.

```
<asp:RangeValidator ControlToValidate="tbValue" MinimumValue='<%# Eval("MinValue") %>' MaximumValue='<%# Eval("MaxValue") %>' Type="Integer" Text="The value is not within the acceptable range!" runat="server" />
```